# Check if Path points to inside of DIRECTORY Or path is a sub directory of DIRECTORY

Tags: php, directory, copy

First of all this is not a duplicate as i haven't found answers related to this.
I have a `Base DIRECTORY` where all my files & folders are located.

```
$base = dirname(__DIR__).'/files';
```

and i want to copy from path to path :

```
$copyFrom = $base.'/our';
$copyTo   = $base.'/New folder';
```

Now What i want is to check at first that the `our` & `New Folder` directories are present inside **$base** So that the Copying should be done inside the **$base** Directory only.

If for example user tries to put `../../` at the end of the copyFrom/copyTo path so the So the system will copy outside To prevent that i need to have a check.

What i have tried is but this just tells me that the directory exists:

```
if (is_dir($base.$copyFrom) && is_dir($base.$copyTo)) {

}
```

**Tried again with this but in vein this is returning `NotPresent` i have 2 directories in $base `our` & `New folder`**

```
                $directories = glob($base . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            foreach ($directories as $result) {
                if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;
                if (is_dir($copyTo == $result)) {
                    echo 'Yes ';
                }else{
                    echo 'NotPresent ';
                    echo $copyTo .'  '. $result . ' | ';   

                }
            }
```

**Echo**

> C:\MAMP\htdocs\projectAuru\our/files/our  C:\MAMP\htdocs\projectAuru\our/files/New folder | C:\MAMP\htdocs\projectAuru\our/files/our  C:\MAMP\htdocs\projectAuru\our/files/our |

Comment: If you have the permissions set correctly, you can also check [`is_writable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php).

Comment: Can you please provide a functional example?

Comment: @NigelRen Please check my updated Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the directories have to be directly under the `$base` folder, you can just check the names are in the list of directories returned by `glob()`...

```
$directories = glob($base . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$copyFrom    = '/our';
$copyTo      = '/New Folder';
// As $directories will have entries like ./dirname, add . to check
if ( in_array(".".$copyFrom, $directories) && in_array(".".$copyTo, $directories) ) {
    echo 'Yes ';
}else{
    echo 'NotPresent ';
}
```

If you wanted to check that the path doesn't have a .. type entry, you could just search the string to check it (adding `/` to the start allows you to check for `/../`)...

```
$copyTo      = '../../New Folder';
if ( strpos("/".$copyTo, "/../") !== false )    {
    echo "trying to change path";
}
else if (is_dir($base.$copyFrom) && is_dir($base.$copyTo)) {
    // Paths are OK and directories exist.
}
```

Comment: Directories can exist directly in $base and also in further sub-folders in $base .What will be the solution for those?

Comment: Added something to check for .. type paths

Comment: This is returning Not Present and i `print_r `the array of directories `NotPresent Array
(
    [0] => C:\MAMP\htdocs\projectAuru\our/files/New folder
    [1] => C:\MAMP\htdocs\projectAuru\our/files/our
)
`

Comment: If you want to just check for .. in the paths - don't use the first code.  The second part should be used before the code you already have (`if (is_dir($base.$copyFrom) && is_dir($base.$copyTo)) {`.

Comment: Forgot to mention i am on windows.As this is returning the whole paths because $base is under `dirname(__DIR__).'/files'` Thus adding $base to `$base.$copyTo` and removing the first `"."`  is Working